# git-svn problems creating tags

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tags, git-svn

First off, I have no problems at all pushing updates to the origin trunk. If I try creating tags or branches, I get the following error:

`git svn tag 4.0.6`

> Copying http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/xxx/trunk at xxx to http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/xxx/tags/4.0.6...
>   Authorization failed: POST of '/!svn/me': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org) at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.4.1/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1196.

I have tried resetting my password, but since I have no problems pulling/pushing updates to/from the trunk, im pretty sure this is not related to my login credentials.

Does anyone have experience with this specific problem? If it is of any relevance of all, Im sitting on OSX Yosemite.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you make a tag via svn? e.g. `svn cp http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/xxx/trunk http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/xxx/tags/4.0.6` ?

Comment: Similar problem here while trying to create a branch: "git svn branch my branch": Authorization failed: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.my.org/svn/repo/project/trunk': OPTIONS of 'https://svn.my.org/svn/repo/project/trunk': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://svn.my.org) at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.5.1/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1196. Checking out stuff and committing to trunk does work, however. I am able to create directories via svn mkdir and do a svn copy.

Comment: I experience the same problems. I'm working with cygwin on Windows 7 with git 2.5.1 and git-svn version 2.5.1 (svn 1.9.1).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem on Windows 7 with Git bash. I was able to push and pull from SVN to Git but could not create branches or tags. I discovered that git-svn was finding the credentials by using procmon to monitor activity from perl. I also have Tortoise SVN installed and could create branches and perform checkouts from it. Recently I installed Ubuntu server in Virtual box to play around with other unrelated things. I decided to see if after installing Git I'd try pulling down a repo and after authenticating found that I could create a branch. I vim-ed the cached SVN.simple credential and noticed that the password was in plain text. I compared the credential with the one on my windows box that git-svn on windows was picking up and noticed that the password was what looked like based 64ed. I thought it was a long shot but I copied the credential from the VM to windows and deleted the other one and git-svn started working. I can now push, pull, create branches and all that wonderful stuff in Git on windows now.

Check to see what the credential looks like and if git-svn finds it. Perhaps the problem is similar to what I experienced. I realize that the password is in plain text but for now it does the job.